# Justify this statement whether correct or incorrect . He2^+ has the same energy as two isolated He atoms

Tags: bond

My explanation : how can a stable molecule be at the same energy level as two isolated inert gas atoms?? Is this even possible?

Comment: I cannot confirm the energy is the same, but if it was, what would make it unstable ? Note also the thermodynamic stability as measure of Gibbs energy difference and kinetic stability as measure of reaction activation energy.

Comment: This statement is not well-formed and cannot be justified as correct or incorrect.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if its supposed to be He$_{2}^{+}$, He$^{2+}$, 2He$^{+}$, or what in the title...

Comment: $\text{He}_2^+$ would not have the same energy as two isolated He atoms.